# Not getting image url from bestseller code

Tags: magento-1.8

I wrote some code for best-seller product in magento  but

I m not getting product image url ....

I need small image  for the gallery..

I m  developing bestseller slider .....the whole thing is good

but only i m not getting image url...

### my code

```
$current_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
        $is_category_filter = Mage::getStoreConfig('productslider/product_setting/category_filter');
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
                            ->addOrderedQty()
                            ->addMinimalPrice()
                            ->addTaxPercents()
                            ->addStoreFilter(); 
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
        if($current_category && $is_category_filter == '1'){
            $current_category_id = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
            $currentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($current_category_id);
            $collection->addCategoryFilter($currentCategory);
        }
        $collection->setPageSize(30);

        $this->setProductCollection($collection);




         return $collection;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is mistake in your code to get collection.
You can try this code to get 5 bestseller products list:

```
$storeId = 'your store id'

$visibility = array(
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                  );
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')    
                        ->setStoreId($storeId)
                        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)    
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)             
                        ->addOrderedQty()
                        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
                        ->setPageSize(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write the following code to display product small image. Inside your product collection loop use the following code.

```
(string) Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(100);
```

Thanks.